# Add generated arrays to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array (generated by a function) that contains arrays and I want to add them to another array.

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $array[] = 
            array(
                'name'          => 'name_'.$element->name,
                'desc'          => 'Stuff for for '.$element->desc,
                'attributes'    => array(),
                'type'          => 'textarea'
            );
}
```

And I have this:

```
$settings['var'] = array(
    array(
        array(
            'name'          => 'Test 1',
            'desc'          => 'This is test 1',
            'attributes'    => array(),
            'type'          => 'textarea'
        ),
        array(
            'name'          => 'Test 2',
            'desc'          => 'This is test 2',
            'attributes'    => array(),
            'type'          => 'textarea'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now I want to add all the elements in the first array (array[]) into the settings array.

If I do it like:

```
$settings['var'] = array(
        array(
            array(
                'name'          => 'Test 1',
                'desc'          => 'This is test 1',
                'attributes'    => array(),
                'type'          => 'textarea'
            ),
            $array[0],
            $array[1]...
```

it works, but I want to add all arrays in $array[] to the array.
I can't use a foreach here, so how can I do that?

Comment: Does the `$settings['var']` array contain anything before your loop? If so, use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).  If not, then just use `$settings['var'] = $array;`

Comment: Are you trying to recursively reduce all sub arrays into a single array?

Answer (score -1):

To get the result you want, you can use `array_merge` inside the array:

```
$settings['var'] = array( array_merge(array1, array2))
```

the elements of `array1` and `array2` are arrays  in your case.

Please refer to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for more details.

Comment: And how can I set the level of the merge? Because I don't want to merge it into the first, but into the second array level (see example)

Comment: Use array_merge inside the array: $settings['var'] = array( array_merge(array1, array2)), the elements of array1 and array2 in your case are arrays.